# Split dates separately

Tags: r

I have a date variable

```
date
15APR16:00:00:04
17APR16:00:06:35
18APR16:00:05:07
18APR16:00:00:56
19APR16:00:08:07
18APR16:00:00:07
22APR16:00:03:07
```

I want split the variable into two as date and time seperatly.
When I tried
`a <- strftime(date, format="%H:%M:%S")`, it is showing

> Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz) :    do not know how to
>   convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

When I tried to see the data type, it shows it as function. How to convert this into date and split into two variables?

Comment: What is the year(s) corresponding to these timestamps?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting that error is because your `date` variable doesn't have the right format yet. You should first convert your `date` variable to a POSIX class with `strptime`:

```
dat$date <- strptime(dat$date, format = '%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S')
```

After that you can use `format` to extract the time from that variable:

```
dat$time <- format(dat$date, "%H:%M:%S")
```

For extracting the date, it is preferrably to use `as.Date`:

```
dat$dates <- as.Date(dat$date)
```

Those steps will give the following result:

```
> dat
                 date     time      dates
1 2016-04-15 00:00:04 00:00:04 2016-04-15
2 2016-04-17 00:06:35 00:06:35 2016-04-17
3 2016-04-18 00:05:07 00:05:07 2016-04-18
4 2016-04-18 00:00:56 00:00:56 2016-04-18
5 2016-04-19 00:08:07 00:08:07 2016-04-19
6 2016-04-18 00:00:07 00:00:07 2016-04-18
7 2016-04-22 00:03:07 00:03:07 2016-04-22
```

Alternative you could use the `lubridate` package (as also shown in the other answer):

```
library(lubridate)
dat$date <- dmy_hms(dat$date)
```

---

Used data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="date
15APR16:00:00:04
17APR16:00:06:35
18APR16:00:05:07
18APR16:00:00:56
19APR16:00:08:07
18APR16:00:00:07
22APR16:00:03:07", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried using dat$date <- strptime(dat$date, format = '%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S')
 Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: what if i have this variable in csv file....when i tried seeing the type of the variable using class...it showing it as function. how to change it

Comment: @suresh that could be because your locale in not correctly set, try setting it first with `Sys.setlocale(category = 'LC_TIME', locale = 'en_US')`

Comment: Is there anyother way to do it....i tried running after executing the above command...it showing the same error.

Comment: Whence is the source of your data?  Could you export it in a format which is more friendly to R?

Comment: @suresh What is the class of your date variable? (use `class(dat$date)` to get that)

Answer (score 1):

Package `lubridate` makes converting text to dates easy

```
library(lubridate)

x <-dmy_hms("15APR16:00:00:04")
format(x, "%H:%M:%S") # extract time
[1] "00:00:04"
format(x, "%d-%m-%Y") # extract date
[1] "15-04-2016"
```